# Ordinary Least Squares

Tags: statistics

There is a statistical model of the form: $Y_j = f(t_j; \theta_0) + \tilde\varepsilon_j$  for $j = 1,2,\ldots,N$.

In the ordinary least squares approach, as N goes to infinity:
$$
\theta_\mathrm{OLS}^{N}\left(Y\right)\sim N\left(\theta_0, \Sigma_0^N\right)\approx N\left(\theta_0, \sigma_0^2 \left[F_\theta^N \left(\theta_0\right)^T F_\theta^N\left(\theta_0\right)\right]^{-1}\right)
$$

where
$$
\left(F_\theta^N\right)_{jk}\left(\theta\right) = \frac{\partial f\left(t_j;\theta\right)}{\partial \theta_k}\\
k=1, 2, \ldots ,\kappa _\theta
$$

and
$$
\sigma_0^2 \approx \hat\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N-\kappa_\theta}\sum_{j=1}^{N} \left[y_j -f\left(t_j ;\hat\theta_\mathrm{OLS}^N\right)\right]^2
$$

What I want to show is:
$$
\frac{\left(N- \kappa_\theta\right)S^2}{\sigma_0^2} \sim \chi_{N-\kappa_\theta}^2
$$
where
$$
S^2=\frac{J_\mathrm{OLS}^N (\theta_\mathrm{OLS}^N ; Y)}{N- \kappa_\theta}=\frac{1}{N-\kappa_\theta}\sum_{j=1}^N [Y_j -f(t_j; \theta_\mathrm{OLS}^N)]^2
$$

If the errors $\tilde\varepsilon _j$  are assumed to be independent and normally distributed with zero mean and constant variance $\sigma_0^2$, then the expression above is distributed as $\chi_{N-\kappa_\theta}^2$.

But what if the errors are not normally distributed? How can I show this by using the Central limit Theorem? How and where can I apply the Central limit theorem? Could you explain this in details?

Comment: I tried to fix the latex. Please ensure I did not unintentionally add any errors.